# How to resolve ValueKind = Object : {} when using a dynamic object without NewtonSoft?

Tags: c#, json

Payload is going into parts.model which is delceared as a Dynamic because it's a service used by multiple endpoints. So I am trying to keep the structure while trying to resolve the ValueKind = Object issue.

This is the Model I am trying to convert back to dynamic.

```
    "Model": {
        "CustomerSurname": "Johnson",
        "Title": "Mr",
        "PlanType": "Help Extension",
        "ServiceAdvisor": "Jeff Matle",
        "DealershipName": "Goldwagen Pretoria"
    },
```

I tried to use JsonSerializer.Deserialize multiple times and it did not work.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendSms([FromBody] CreatePart parts)
        {
            parts.DateMessageScheduled = DateTime.Now;
            parts.DateCutOff = DateTime.MaxValue;
            parts.CommunicationTypeId = CommunicationType.Codes.SMS;

            dynamic obj = parts.Model;

            JsonElement jsonString = obj;

            var dynamicObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(jsonString);

            var result = await _createNewPartService.Post(parts);

            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
```

Results of dynamicObject :

```
ValueKind = Object : "{
        "CustomerSurname": "Johnson",
        "Title": "Mr",
        "PlanType": "Help Extension",
        "ServiceAdvisor": "Jeff Matle",
        "DealershipName": "Goldwagen Pretoria"
    }"
```

Comment: TBH it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve here. And what is _"the ValueKind = Object issue"_. What do you mean by that. Also I would argue that using `dynamic` is usually a code smell.

Comment: _"delceared as a Dynamic because it's a service used by multiple endpoints"_ - that makes no sense at all - weak-typing is completely orthogonal to how popular a web-service is... - and I agree with @GuruStron: if you're using `dynamic` for anything more than a sketch or bodge (or maybe an _urgent_ fix...) then you're only creating future problems for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    var dict = System.Text.Json
          .JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);

    dynamic dynamicObj = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        dynamic innerObj = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var word in item.Value)
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)innerObj).Add(word.Key, word.Value);

        ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynamicObj).Add(item.Key, innerObj);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(dynamicObj.Model.Title);
```

but as @Dai wrote in comments "Just because you can do this, doesn't mean that you should"